# Java Executor Service Connection Pool

Tags: java, connection-pooling, executorservice, apache-commons-dbcp, scheduledexecutorservice

I am attempting to use connection pooling for Executor Service.

I am facing some problem when connection pool config is initialSize=3, maxToal=5, maxIdle=5.

I need to process 10 services at a time for every minute. But its picking only 5 services for every minute.

If i configure initialSize=3, maxToal=10, maxIdle=10 then its picking 10 services for every minute..

I am new to multithreading and connection. Below is my  code snippet. Please provide suggestion.

```
public class TestScheduledExecutorService {
    public static void main (String a[]) {
        ScheduledExecutorService service = null;
        try {
            TestObject runnableBatch = new TestObject() {
                public void run() {
                    testMethod ();
                }
            };
            service = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
            service.scheduleAtFixedRate(runnableBatch, 0, 30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public class TestObject implements Runnable{

    public void testMethod (int inc) {
        ExecutorService service = null;
        try {
            service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                service.submit(new TestService());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
    }
}

public class TestService implements Callable{

    Connection conn = null;

    public void process(Connection conn) {
        try {
            if (conn != null) {
                System.out.println("Thread & Connection pool conn : "+Thread.currentThread() + " :: " +conn);
                // service process here
            } else {
                System.out.println("Connection pool conn is null : ");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Object call() throws Exception {
        ConnectionPoolTest cp = ConnectionPoolTest.getInstance();
        BasicDataSource bds = cp.getBasicDataSource();
        conn = bds.getConnection();
        System.out.println(" call() "); **// it prints only 5 times for every minute eventhough total services are 10**
        process(conn);
        return null;
    }

}

public class ConnectionPoolTest {

private static ConnectionPoolTest dataSource = new ConnectionPoolTest();

    private static BasicDataSource basicDataSource = null;

    private ConnectionPoolTest() {  
    }

    public static ConnectionPoolTest getInstance() { 
        if (dataSource == null) 
            dataSource = new ConnectionPoolTest();
        return dataSource;
    }

    public BasicDataSource getBasicDataSource() throws Exception {
        try {
            basicDataSource = new BasicDataSource();

            basicDataSource.setInitialSize(3);
            basicDataSource.setMaxTotal(10);
            basicDataSource.setMaxIdle(10);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw e;
        }
        return basicDataSource;
    }

}
```

Comment: Your "singleton" is broken. You're not supposed to create a new `BasicDataSource` each time like you're doing now.

Comment: Thanks Kayaman. Can you please tell me the solution for this.

Comment: There's no simple solution. Your code is wrong in so many ways, that I'd recommend doing some reading (tutorials, other stackoverflow posts etc.) about both connection pools and executors. Currently you're using both of them in completely wrong ways.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback Kayaman, Can you please updated the code if you can. it will be more helpful for me.

Comment: Kayaman.. i have printed the Sinlgleton object.. it gives same object for all 10 services.. i think singleton is working as expected.

Comment: It's the same `ConnectionPoolTest` instance, but not the same `BasicDataSource` instance. You create a new one on each get.

Comment: Thanks Fildor, Noted my mistake.

Comment: Fildor, conn = bds.getConnection(); i have printed conn object, it differs for every 10 set connections from pool..140092839, URL=XXX UserName=XXX, Oracle JDBC driver

Answer (score 2):

For Executor Service

```
 initialSize : Specified Number of Threads to spin , when New executor is created.
 maxTotal    : Number of Threads that can exist at max peak load.
 maxIdle     : Number of Thread that are kept active even if load goes below threshold.
```

As you mentioned, you want to pick up 10 number of tasks in parallel, we should have **maxTotal** set at 10. **intialSize** can be configured to a number that you think is optimal at the start , lets say 3 - 5. **maxIdle** is the number of threads you want to keep active , we generally assume how many threads are required if tasks are submitted. though there is no standard recomendation, vaues might be determined a number of various factors like .

1. Distribution of task submitted during the minute
2. Duration of Task
3. Urgency of executing those tasks in parallel.

As you mentioned you need 10 parallel tasks, then you will have to configure 10 as maxTotal, considering your task distribution and Duration causes overlap. If duration is pretty small , and distribution is even you can also survive with a lower number too.

Comment: If you look at the code however, you'll notice that he's actually using a fixed threadpool of `10` threads, and the configurations are for the *connection pool*.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
duration is small only. ExecutorService is not depend on Connection pool right. You are saying Specified Number of Threads to spin, i cnfigured 3, but it takes 5 services parallel.